# Aggregating the unknown csv files for a particular folder

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have some number of csv files in a folder.
`water`folder has `water_202201.csv` , `water_202202.csv`and  `water_202203.csv`.I want to aggregate these 3 files. Of course, I can do like the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
dat1=pd.read_csv("C:/water/water_202201.csv")
dat2=pd.read_csv("C:/water/water_202202.csv")
dat3=pd.read_csv("C:/water/water_202202.csv")
frames=[data1,data2,data3]
result1=pd.concat(frames)
result1
```

But the question is how to aggregate if I don't know how many csv files are in the `water`folder and somehow I want to aggregate every csv files inside that folder.
202201 means 2022 January

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pathlib` to iterate over your folder:

```
import pathlib

data = {}
for file in pathlib.Path('C:/water').glob('water_*.csv'):
    date = file.stem.split('_')[-1]  # extract 202201 for water_202201.csv
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    data[date] = df

# One-line version
data = {file.stem.split('_')[1]: pd.read_csv(file) 
           for file in pathlib.Path('./data/water').glob('water_*.csv')}
```

Now 2 possibilities:

Prefix the index by the `date` key:

```
df = pd.concat(data)
```

Without prefix:

```
df = pd.concat(data.values())
```

Comment: I tried ,but only  the latest csv file in that folder is used .

Comment: All filenames are different, right?

Comment: What is the output of `len(data)` and `data.keys()` after the loop, please?

Comment: I misunderstood. Your code works!

Comment: I'm sorry,but what if the data name is `water_machine A_202201.csv`  ?                                         How can I change  `date = file.stem.split('_')[1]`  ?

Comment: If the date is the last part of the name before the extension, use `date = file.stem.split('_')[-1]` (note the -1 instead of 1)

Comment: I updated my answer and replace 1 by -1. Now it's work for `water_202201.csv` and `water_machine A_202201.csv`